# How to reset windows 10? When drive is corrupted

Tags: windows-10, reset, filesystem-corruption, bootrepair

How to reset my acer predator laptop? My C drive is corrupted as my laptop force shut down during an update.

It's stuck in boot and won't go past troubleshooting screen.

Tried:

Alt+f10 to reset, no option to be seen

Media creation tool to repair

Media creation tool to install new windows (Says the drive may fail and can't install windows)

Tried inserting an additional new drive to install windows, didn't work same error

Any help would be appreciated, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it's still under warranty.

You should call up the Acer Support Hotline.

A lesson learnt is that you have to give Windows 24 hours to update completely. It must not be stopped when it tells not to stop it.

Otherwise there could be a failing hard disk that needs to be replaced.